# SQLNCLI.1 in connection string

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, sql-server-native-client, sqlncli

I am working with two different database components in my application and have come across a curious behavior regarding the SQL Server Native Client versions (SQLNCLI.1 and SQLNCLI11) in connection strings.

First Component Behavior: One of the database components I am using automatically generates a connection string that includes Provider=SQLNCLI.1. Surprisingly, this works seamlessly even though I have only SQL Server Native Client 11 (SQLNCLI11) installed on my PC.

Second Component Behavior: Another component in my application uses SQLNCLI11 explicitly in the connection string. It also functions correctly, as expected, since SQLNCLI11 is installed on my machine.

Given this context, I have several questions:

What are the primary differences between SQLNCLI.1 and SQLNCLI11? I Thought SQLNCLI.1 is older?
Is there some form of backward compatibility or aliasing in SQL Server Native Clients that would explain why SQLNCLI.1 works even though only SQLNCLI11 is installed?

Comment: What connection strings? In what language? What application? You don't need to specify the driver name in ADO.NET and the Native Client can't be used in Python or Java. The Native Client is obsolete anyway, with the last version released in 2012. [The docs themselves](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver15) warn it's obsolete and actually removed in SQL Server 2022. It's not used in ODBC (the suggested alternative) or OLEDB

Comment: `this works seamlessly` probably because there's no other version installed on your machine and your own code uses v11 libraries directly

Comment: SQLNCLI = SQL 2005 native client, SQLNCLI10 = SQL 2008 native client, SQLNCLI11 = SQL 2012 native client. . I'm not aware of any aliasing that would transparently use a different version but different versions can be installed side-by-side.

Comment: Run this to list installed OLE DB providers: `powershell -Command "$providers = @(); foreach ($provider in [System.Data.OleDb.OleDbEnumerator]::GetRootEnumerator()) {for ($i = 0; $i -lt $provider.FieldCount; $i++) { $provider | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $provider.GetName($i) -NotePropertyValue $provider.GetValue($i) } $providers += $provider } $providers | Select SOURCES_NAME, SOURCES_DESCRIPTION | Sort-Object SOURCES_DESCRIPTION | Format-Table"`